# Multi select option is not refreshed with jquery

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using a multi select jquery plugin and I want to select some options by random. I am randomizing the multi select correctly but my multi select is not showing selected items. If I use the same code in `document.ready` it works fine but when I use it in a button event multi select is not showing selected items.

What is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my-select').searchableOptionList();
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-primary", function () {
        var count=$(this).attr("data-random-max");
        randomElements = jQuery("#my-select option").get().sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
        }).slice(0,count);
        var vals = new Array();
        $(randomElements).each(function(){
            vals.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("#my-select").val(vals);
        $("#my-select").multiselect("refresh");
    });
});
```

Here is my multi select code:

```
<select style="margin-top: 20px; display: none;" multiple="multiple" id="my-select">
    <optgroup label="ساده">
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="متوسط">
        <option value="1">سیب</option>
        <option value="3">آیا در انجام مسیولیت کوشا هستید؟</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="سخت">
        <option value="7">آیا آماده است؟</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

and my `vals` variable is 1,3,7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have on trick.. I hope it works

$('#my-select').multiselect('select', vals);

I am not sure it works as I have not tested.

Comment: try with my edited answer, $('#my-select').multiselect('select', vals);

Comment: here document provided for multiselect library..  http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods

Comment: Unfortunately its not working yet. I dont know why it is not working!

Comment: can you provide log of vals variable? and HTML of #my-select?

Comment: I updated the question.After clicking on button if I refresh the page using F5 the multi select is configured correctly.

Comment: I cant se option with value 5 and 7

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but this should select random elements from the select

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-primary", function () {
        var count=$(this).attr("data-random-max");
        var len = $("#my-select option").length;
        for (var i = 0;i < count;i++) {
         var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*len) + 1;
         $("#my-select option").eq(index).attr('selected','selected');
        }

        $("#my-select").multiselect("refresh");
    });
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h86zdg57/